# DataTables set aoColumns after getting server data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTables with server side data to display several tables with details (expanding sub tables). There are two types of sub tables one with three columns one with 7 columns.

I would like to set the value of `aoColumns` after I have retrieved data from the server and before the row is displayed but Im having a hard time doing it. Here is what I have so far.

```
self.createDataTable = function(identifier, source, rowCallback, initCallback) {
var columnsA = [
        { "mDataProp": "index", "sClass": "index", "bSortable": false },
        { "mDataProp": "text", "sClass": "top-dd", "bSortable": false },
        { "mDataProp": "stats", "sClass": "top-dd stats", "bSortable": false }
    ];
var columnsB = [
        { "mDataProp": "index", "sClass": "index", "bSortable": false },
        { "mDataProp": "check-box", "sClass": "check-box" },
        { "mDataProp": "foundDate", "sClass": "date" },
        { "mDataProp": "pageLink", "sClass": "link" },
        { "mDataProp": "linkText", "sClass": "text" },
        { "mDataProp": "ipAddress", "sClass": "ip" },
        { "mDataProp": "otherLinks", "sClass": "more dd-second-" + thisTR.id }
    ];

$(identifier).dataTable({
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bSort": true,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "oLanguage": { "sEmptyTable": 'No patterns found' },
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": source,
    "fnServerParams": function(aoData) {
        aoData.push({ "name": "uniqueid", "value": self.uniqueid },
                    { "name": "basedomain", "value": basedomain },
                    { "name": "return_this", "value": $(this).data('returnid') });
    },
    "aoColumns": columnsA,
    "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {                
        return rowCallback(nRow, aData);
    },
    "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, iStart, iEnd, iMax, iTotal, sPre) {
        initCallback();
    }

});
```

Basically I would like to catch data from the server, look at a flag passed from the server, set aoColumns and then continue as normal. Any ideas? Im looking through the callback functions http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks but Im having a hard time setting the columns once Im in a callback.

I'm also reading the following but Im not getting the desired results.

- [Altering jquery datatables aoColumns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671552/altering-jquery-datatables-aocolumns)
- http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found a solution though its a little round about. Basically I create a columns variable with all possible columns. I set `aoColumns` using this variable and I also add the variable to my `aoData` and send it to the server.

Here's my server side PHP code:

```
$returnArray = $patternHandler->getGroupsForSection($_GET['return_this']);

if(count($returnArray) > 0) {
    $hiddenCoulumns = array();
    $columns = json_decode($_GET['columns'], true);
    $testRow = $returnArray[0];

    for($i = 0; $i < count($columns); $i++) {
        if(!isset($testRow[$columns[$i]['mDataProp']])) {
            foreach($returnArray AS &$row) {
                $row[$columns[$i]['mDataProp']] = '';
                $hiddenCoulumns[] = $i;
            }
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode(array(
            'sEcho' => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
            'iTotalRecords' => count($returnArray),
            'iTotalDisplayRecords' => count($returnArray),
            'aaData' => $returnArray,
            'hiddenColumns' => $hiddenCoulumns));
```

You see that I get the $returnArray (my formatted associative array representing data table rows) as normal. Then I loop through my `columns` variable that I passed. If a value for  `mDataProp` isn't in my return array I just add a blank string to make data tables happy.

So if I stopped here I would have a bunch of blank columns in each row for my data table. To hide the empty columns I return a array of $hiddenColumns back to the "fnServerData" function which is the callback for the ajax call that gets the data. Here I just loop through my returned hiddenColumns and hide them. The user is none the wiser :)

Here's my JavaScript:

```
self.createDataTable = function(identifier, source, rowCallback, initCallback) {
    var columns = [
        { "mDataProp": "index", "sClass": "index", "bSortable": false },
        { "mDataProp": "text", "sClass": "top-dd", "bSortable": false },
        { "mDataProp": "stats", "sClass": "top-dd stats", "bSortable": false },
        { "mDataProp": "check-box", "sClass": "check-box" },
        { "mDataProp": "foundDate", "sClass": "date" },
        { "mDataProp": "pageLink", "sClass": "link" },
        { "mDataProp": "linkText", "sClass": "text" },
        { "mDataProp": "ipAddress", "sClass": "ip" },
        { "mDataProp": "otherLinks", "sClass": "more dd-second-" }
    ];

    var patternsTable = $(identifier).dataTable({
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "oLanguage": { "sEmptyTable": 'No patterns found' },
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": source,
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            /* Add some extra data to the sender */
            aoData.push( { "name": "more_data", "value": "my_value" } );
            $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) { 
                    /* Get server data callback */
                    for(var i = 0; i < json.hiddenColumns.length; i++) {
                        patternsTable.fnSetColumnVis(json.hiddenColumns[i], false);
                    }
                    fnCallback(json)
            } );
        },
        "fnServerParams": function(aoData) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "uniqueid", "value": self.uniqueid },
                        { "name": "basedomain", "value": basedomain },
                        { "name": "return_this", "value": $(this).data('returnid') },
                        { "name": "columns", "value": JSON.stringify(columns)});
        },
        "aoColumns": columns,
        "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {                
            return rowCallback(nRow, aData);
        },
        "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, iStart, iEnd, iMax, iTotal, sPre) {
            initCallback();
        }

    });
}
```